# How can I use entity save in drupal 8

Tags: forms

I'm installed drupal 8 in local and created a content type named as  **Project** with minimal fields. And implemented form API to collect data in custom module.

Here how can I save the data as node content?
or How can I use entity save in drupal 8

Comment: It depends on what you need to achieve, what kind of data you're saving it, where you want to save it to in the database, etc. Without knowing more about your setup it's hard to give a good quality answer. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use normal fields for this?

Comment: My content type project having only two fields. 1. project title and 2. Estimated time. And i want to save the data as a node content. I'm new to drupal so i'm not too much experienced with drupal database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want save node type. You can use code example below

```
<?php

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
$node = Node::create([
  // The node entity bundle.
  'type' => 'article',
  'langcode' => 'en',
  'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'changed' => REQUEST_TIME,
  // The user ID.
  'uid' => 1,
  'title' => 'My test!',
  // An array with taxonomy terms.
  'field_tags' =>[2],
  'body' => [
    'summary' => '',
    'value' => '<p>The body of my node.</p>',
    'format' => 'full_html',
  ],
]);
$node->save();
```